# Can't ssh to instance

Tags: 12.04, ssh

I have a linode instance, I was successfully connecting to it via ssh.

But I've decided to rebuild my instance and then I can not connect to that instance via ssh.

The linode works correctly because I can get access via Lish (lonode ssh)

I've tried to clear known_hosts with:

```
ssh-keygen -R 212.71.xxx.xx
```

But I still getting message:

```
 ssh root@212.71.xxx.xx -v

OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 212.71.238.74 [212.71.238.74] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/megas/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/megas/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/megas/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/megas/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/megas/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/megas/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA c5:c3:a7:c0:5a:25:a1:64:c4:04:0c:42:bb:46:f6:96
debug1: Host '212.71.238.74' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/megas/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/megas/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/megas/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/megas/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

How to resolve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd try SSHing in without a key and then re-uploading yours.

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host
```